# Intervention Image Laravel - Keep File Extension

Tags: php, image, laravel, intervention

How would I go about making uploaded images keep their extensions using intervention image?

This is the current code I have for saving a user's avatar:

```
/**
* Saves avatar in filesystem.
*
* @param  UploadedImage $image
* @param  string $path
* @return void
*/
public function saveAvatar($image, array $paths)
{
foreach ($paths as $k => $v)
{
  //delete any previous user avatars
  File::delete(public_path($v));

  if ($k == 'big')
  {
    $encoded = Imagine::make($image['avatar']->getRealPath())
      ->resize(300, 300);

    Imagine::make($encoded)->save(public_path($v), 100);
  }
  else
  {
    $encoded = Imagine::make($image['avatar']->getRealPath())
      ->resize(100, 100);

    Imagine::make($encoded)->save(public_path($v), 100);
  }
}
}
```

This codes splits the file into 2 files and big and and an original, but they get saved as jpegs by default, but what if I want both jpeg and png to be saved not only one extension.

This is the process of uploading via the Controller (Recently Changed it):

```
 /**
  * Uploads and associates user avatar.
  *
  * @param  string $username
  * @return void
  */
  public function avatar($name)
  {
    $input = ['avatar' => Input::file('avatar')];
    $inputExt = pathinfo( $input->getClientOriginalName() );

    if ( ! $this->validator->setRules('avatar')->with($inputExt)->passes())
    {
      return Redirect::back()->withErrors($this->validator->errors());
    }

    $this->user->uploadAvatar($inputExt, $name);

    return Redirect::back()->withSuccess( trans('users.uploaded avatar success') );
}
```

and this is the UserRepository

```
  /**
   * Uploads provided avatar and associates with user.
   *
   * @param  array  $input
   * @param  string $id
   * @return void
   */
  public function uploadAvatar(array $input, $id)
  {
    $user = User::find($id);

    $paths['big'] = "assets/uploads/avatars/$id";
    $paths['small'] = "assets/uploads/avatars/$id.small";

    $this->images->saveAvatar($input, $paths);

    $user->avatar = $paths['big'];
    $user->save();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my code to save image in different size for a particular project, I think it answers your question.

```
     /**
     * Save image. Generate Different Size versions.
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @param null $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function storeImages(Request $request, $id = null)
    {
        try {
            $project   = Project::find($id);
            $imageInfo = pathinfo(Input::file('image')->getClientOriginalName());
            //append image name with project id
            $imageName      = $imageInfo['filename'] . '_' . $id . '.' . $imageInfo['extension'];
            $smallImageName = $imageInfo['filename'] . '_' . $id . '_small' . '.' . $imageInfo['extension'];
            $thumbImageName = $imageInfo['filename'] . '_' . $id . '_thumb' . '.' . $imageInfo['extension'];

            if (Image::where('name', '=', $imageName)->count()) { //if already have this image, delete it
                Image::where('name', '=', $imageName)->delete();
            }
            $prefix     = Image::getPathPrefix();
            $uploadPath = config('app.image_paths.PROJECT') . $id . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

            if (!Storage::exists($uploadPath)) {
                Storage::makeDirectory($uploadPath);
            }

            $image = \Image::make(Input::file('image'))->save($prefix . $uploadPath . $imageName);
            $image->fit(config('app.image_size.SMALL.height'),
                config('app.image_size.SMALL.width'))->save($prefix . $uploadPath . $smallImageName);
            $image->fit(config('app.image_size.THUMB.height'),
                config('app.image_size.THUMB.width'))->save($prefix . $uploadPath . $thumbImageName);

            $imageObj = Image::create([
                'name'              => $imageName,
                'small_image'       => $smallImageName,
                'thumb_image'       => $thumbImageName,
                'original_filename' => $imageInfo['basename'],
                'mime'              => $image->mime(),
                'created_at'        => Carbon::now(),
                'updated_at'        => Carbon::now(),
                'upload_path'       => $uploadPath
            ]);

            $project->images()->save($imageObj);

            return json_encode([
                'jsonrpc' => '2.0',
                'result'  => 'OK',
                'id'      => $imageObj->id
            ]);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return json_encode([
                'jsonrpc' => '2.0',
                'result'  => false,
                'id'      => $e->getMessage()
            ]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: this is everywhere :/ cant really get what this is.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who stumbles upon this as I did:

```
Intervention\Image\Image::save()
```

The image type will be defined by the file extension. For example if you pass foo.jpg the image will be saved as a JPG file. **If there is no extension
available, the library will first try to use the MIME type of the image to define the encoding, if this also fails the image will be encoded as JPEG.**

http://image.intervention.io/api/save

This feature only encodes the image to the correct mime type and does not add an extension. You still need to detect the extension of the file and append it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that you're double "make"ing.

This should solve the issue:

```
/**
* Saves avatar in filesystem.
*
* @param  UploadedImage $image
* @param  string $path
* @return void
*/
public function saveAvatar($image, array $paths)
{
foreach ($paths as $k => $v)
{
  //delete any previous user avatars
  File::delete(public_path($v));

  if ($k == 'big')
  {
    $encoded = Imagine::make($image['avatar']->getRealPath())
      ->resize(300, 300)->save(public_path($v), 100);
  }
  else
  {
    $encoded = Imagine::make($image['avatar']->getRealPath())
      ->resize(100, 100)->save(public_path($v), 100);
  }
}
}
```